# How to hide <div> </div> if the input text is null

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to hide   if the input text is null.
    this are my script code

```
             $(document).ready(function(){
              var taena = document.getElementById("no2").value;

                  if (taena === "") {
                      $('#hideall').hide();

                  else{
                      $('#hideall').show();
                  }
                  });
```

Comment: Looks like your code should work provided that ids like no2 and hideall must be unique in html file

Comment: What is the id of your div?

Comment: You're missing a brace in the if/else statement

Comment: omg! lol. sorry my eye sight is getting weaker. thanks bro.

Answer (score 3):

You can rather trim out spaces from returned value and check for length and then do show hide decision based on it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#hideall').toggle($("#no2").val().trim().length > 0);
});
```

Comment: @PranavCBalan: you are right :) . i need to add the check for bool here. thanks again